# Tkinter with openweather

Tags: python, json, tkinter

I tried creating a dropdown box in Tkinter. I was hoping that everytime i selected a country and click onto the left button, it'll display the weather of the country that I have selected. Apparently, I have to manually change this line of code(in the define weather function) `weather_status = output['list'][2]['sys']`
 every time i want to get the country's weather. How do I get the country's weathers without having to change that line of code manually?

```
import requests
import tkinter as tk 
from tkinter import Tk, BOTH, Menu, StringVar, messagebox, Label

def weather(): 
    city = city_list.get()
    url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/group?id=1880252,524901,703448,2643743&units=metric&appid=de9880142c6480331da965bf187a4b6e'.format(city)
    req = requests.get(url)
    output = req.json()
    weather_status = output['list'][2]['sys']
    weather_status_label.configure(text = 'weather status: ' + str(weather_status))

window = tk.Tk() 
window.geometry('400x350') 

## adding a drop box
OptionList= [
             'Singapore', 
             'London', 
             'Bangkok',
             'Moscow' 
             ]
city_list = StringVar(window, OptionList)
city_list.set('select the city')
opt = tk.OptionMenu(window, city_list, *OptionList)
opt.config(width = 90, font = ('Arial', 12))
opt.pack()

## adding a label on top
lbl = tk.Label(window, text = 'Select your city', bg = 'light green')
lbl.pack()

## adding buttons
def win_quit():
    if messagebox.askokcancel('quit','Do you want to quit?'):
        window.destroy()

button_1 = tk.Button(window, text = 'Quit', height = 2, 
                     width = 4, command = win_quit, activeforeground = 'red',
                     relief = 'ridge')
button_1.place(x= 300, y= 60)

button_2 = tk.Button(window, text = 'Click', height = 2, 
                     width = 4, command = weather, activeforeground = 'green',
                     relief = 'ridge')
button_2.place(x= 70, y= 60)

## adding another label 

weather_status_label = Label(window, font=('Arial', 10,'bold' ))
weather_status_label.pack(padx= 10, pady= 60)

window.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: You can use the `city` returned by `city_list.get()` to construct the url: `url = 'http://.../data/2.5/weather?q={}&units=metrics&appid=...'.format(city)`, and then get the weather status by `weather_status = output['sys']`.

Comment: @acw1668 this worked. Thanks so much! I was trying to figure out how to trace it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I have understood your question, you can do it by "tracing" changes to the `StringVar` named `city_list` and having it call the `weather()` function everytime its value is changed.

Tracing is described in the document [The Variable Classes (BooleanVar, DoubleVar, IntVar, StringVar)](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm).

To make it so you don't have to change the `weather_status = output['list'][2]['sys']` statement in the `weather()` function, you can just make it reference the current `city` value you already have:

```
def weather():
    city = city_list.get()
    url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/group?id=1880252,524901,703448,2643743&units=metric&appid=de9880142c6480331da965bf187a4b6e'.format(city)
    req = requests.get(url)
    output = req.json()

#    weather_status = output['list'][2]['sys']  # CHANGED.
    weather_status = city

    weather_status_label.configure(text = 'weather status: ' + str(weather_status))
```

And then add the code to do the tracing by calling this modified version of it:

```
...
## adding a drop box
OptionList= [
             'Singapore',
             'London',
             'Bangkok',
             'Moscow'
             ]
city_list = StringVar(window, OptionList)
city_list.set('select the city')

observer = city_list.trace('w', lambda *_: weather())  # ADDED.

opt = tk.OptionMenu(window, city_list, *OptionList)
opt.config(width = 90, font = ('Arial', 12))
opt.pack()
...
```

Comment: got it! but what do i do with this "weather_status = output['list'][2]['sys']"? I believe its still tagged to the 3rd City ID in the URL.